# how to add include path for language servers in coc-settings.json file?

Tags: c++, c, vim-plugin, neovim, clangd

I am using neovim plugin ["coc-nvim"](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim), as the IntelliSense tool for C/C++. as I know this plugin is actually a client of language servers like ccls, clangd and cquery. I have all of these language servers installed on my system and configured them to work with coc-nvim. so I can get autocompletion and list of general headers(e.g. stdio and ...) in my c/c++ files. but since I work in ros platform I want to add the headers of the ros(/opt/ros/kinetic/include/**) to my default include path of language servers. with out this option, at the beginning of each project I must add a dummy ros node and compile with `catkin_make -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES` to generate the compile_commands.json file to get access to ros headers.

the settings of coc.nvim is alongside the init.vim file, in a file called "coc-settings.json" and the contents of my coc setting file is as below:

```
{

"languageserver": {
    "clangd": {
      "command": "clangd",
      "rootPatterns": ["compile_flags.txt", "compile_commands.json"],
      "filetypes": ["c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp"]
    },
    "cquery": {
      "command": "/home/amirrezasadeghi/ManBuildLibs/cquery/build/cquery",
      "args": ["--log-file=/tmp/cq.log"],
      "filetypes": ["c", "cpp"],
      "rootPatterns": ["compile_flags.txt", "compile_commands.json", ".git/", ".hg/"],
      "initializationOptions": {
        "cacheDirectory": "/tmp/cquery"
      }
    },
    "ccls": {
      "command": "ccls",
      "filetypes": ["c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp"],
      "rootPatterns": [".ccls", "compile_commands.json", ".git/", ".hg/"],
      "initializationOptions": {
         "cache": {
           "directory": "/tmp/ccls"
         }
       }
    }
  },
  "clangd.semanticHighlighting": true
}
```

So my major question is how to add ros include path to these settings. I checked the [wiki page of coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki) but can't find any option for user include path. also, I checked the option of clangd and tried to add, 
`"args":["-I/opt/ros/kinetic/include/"]`,
to the corresponding block but it did not work. also, I added [.cquery](https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery/wiki/.cquery) file, but still no effect on the list of the proposed headers.

sorry for long story, and thanks for your time.

Edit: it would be better to use the clangd LSP rather than ccls. because it is faster and has better documentation. thanks!

Edit(12 April 2020): the best solution which I found is using ccls language server by using the `extraArgs` which is provided by ccls. so if you add `"clang"` field to ccls configs we can have ros headers in autocompletion.

```
"initializationOptions": {                                                                                        
                                    "cache": {                                                                                                
                                            "directory": "/tmp/ccls"                
                                    },                                              
                                    "clang": {                                      
                                            "extraArgs": [                          
                                                    "-I",                           
                                                    "/opt/ros/kinetic/include/"     
                                            ]                                       
                                    }                                               
                            }
```

but as I mentioned I would like to use clangd if possible. I checked everywhere but no answer. can anyone help me? (please!).

Comment: `Edit(12 April 2020):` Please post this as an answer. Could you please post a full coc-settings.json example?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't fix the problem in the way you asked, but I found it to be a useful solution.

Like you, I used `catkin_make` to generate the `compile_commands.json` using:

```
catkin_make --cmake-args -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```

However, I created a symlink between `<catkin_ws>/build/compile_commands.json` and `<catkin_ws>/compile_commands.json`. Since clangd searches parent directories for `compile_commands.json`, this is accessible by any package/node within the workspace.

Therefore, only one `compile_commands.json` needs to be generated for the whole workspace, and only needs to be re-generated whenever dependencies change.

Comment: Hello Zach. Welcome to StackOverflow. I like your answer but ... can you edit your code and put catkin_make command line on a single line using {} formatting; it is proper to user {} than `text`. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no option in `coc-nvim` for setting that.
Best option is to rely on your LSP options.

I just solved it for `ccls` by defining a custom `.ccls` file and added a `-I` option pointing at my boost includes. That `.ccls` file must be at the root of my project. e.g.:

```
clang
%c
-I/usr/local/include
```

There must be the same option for `clangd`.